# How to remove a binding from a style setter in code behind?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, code-behind

I have WPF datagrid, where the user will add columns at runtime. I'm defining the foreground of each cell of the new column using a binding and valueconverter like this:

```
//binding for color
Binding bindingForeground = new Binding
{
    Converter = new BatchAnalysisForegroundConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = columnStartIndex + i,
    Mode = BindingMode.OneTime
};

//set the foreground binding to the cell style
Style originalCellStyle = Application.Current.TryFindResource(typeof(DataGridCell)) as Style;
Style newCellStyle = new Style
{
    BasedOn = originalCellStyle,
    TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell)
};
newCellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, bindingForeground));
batchCol.CellStyle = newCellStyle;
```

When later at runtime when the user decides to remove that column, I do so like this:

```
  dg.Columns.Remove(inColumn);
```

However, the problem is that even though the column is removed, the binding keeps going, causing the value converter code to run on the removed column.

I could solve this by adding a check in the value converter, to prevent running code on the removed column, but I would prefer to remove the binding.

I tried by setting the path of the binding to `null`, but get an error: 'Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.'

I tried `BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(inColumn)`, didn't work.

I tried `originalCellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, null))` but get the error 'After a 'SetterBaseCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.'

I tried `originalCellStyle.Setters.RemoveAt(2)` and get the same error.

How would I do that?

Comment: Since the `Binding` is applied by an implicit `Style`, it is set to every cell in the `DataGrid`. So when you remove a column and there are columns left, the `Style` still finds a target, therefore the `Binding.Converter` is active. But since your `Binding.Mode` is set to `OneTime` the `Binding` is only executed once during the source's lifetime. It is impossible that the `Binding.Converter` is active more than once under this circumstances.

Comment: How do you know that the converter is still active (on this particular cell i.e. column)? What triggers this converter, when there are no property changes on the data source - on a `OneTime` binding?

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you for your comments, I now understand a little better what's happening. The converter is not running on the removed column, but the converter parameter is still set to the old column index even after a column is removed, that's why everything went haywire when the user removes a column before the last one. I changed the parameter to the column, and attached an object to the tag of the column that contains the column index which is updated when a column is removed. Now, I can retrieve the new column index in the converter and all is well.

Comment: @BionicCode As for the binding mode, it doesn't make any difference which mode it's set to, the converter runs whenever the datagrid scrolls, presumably to update the new cells which become visible. Not sure if I should write an answer to this question, or just leave it. Probably not much help for anyone.

Comment: Yea indeed, the Binding will always initialize its target property as soon the element is loaded, which is when the element is scrolled into view. In order to fix the parameter issue, you should post the converter implementation.

Comment: The best solution is to get the index dynamically. You are currently setting the parameter to a static (fixed) value. Since the same converter is applied to all items, it should be implemented to reflect this. So, you should get the current index dynamically. From the little that you have posted I assume that you are binding to the `DataGridCell`, which is therefore the value of the converter. If so, you can get the current cell's column index directly by accessing `DataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex`. This eliminates the need for the `ConverterParameter` and is much cleaner then any workaround.

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you, I wasn't aware you could get the column index from the DisplayIndex property.